# img not resizing by percentage when in div

Tags: html, css, image

I have this code but the image stays at its original size.

```
                <div style="margin: 10px; align: center;">
                    <img height="40%" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ photo }}" />
                </div>
```

If I remove the div, then it resizes perfectly though.

What do I need to do to make it resize correctly even inside the div?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is suppose to take 40% of your div's size, but your div is empty and it does not have a size specified, this means by default your div's size will be set to `auto`(meaning it will resize based on content). thats why the image does not resize, do this:

```
<div style="margin: 10px; align: center; width:500px; height:500px;">
            <img height="40%" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ photo }}" />
            </div>
```

**Here is a demo:**

```html
<div style="margin: 10px; align: center; width:500px; height:500px;">
    <img height="40%" src="http://www.cypresspa.com/images/img/home-1-bg-3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - you're right. One issue though, now I have a div height of 500 - when I resize the image I'm left with a huge gap at the bottom now? How can I remove that big gap? Thank you

Comment: @b85411 `height:500px` was just an example, you can use any height you want. To get rid of the gap, you need to make the image size equals to the div size, e.g if your div height = 500px, your img height should also be = 500px

Comment: How can I ascertain the image size? I'm displaying the images dynamically, and I don't know the sizes as they could be portrait or landscape. Can I determine from the base64 what the dimensions are?

Comment: @b85411 OR simply do this on your image `height="100%"; width:100%;`

Comment: @b85411 if you set the image size to 100%(see example above), it will dynamically fill up all the space provided by the div

Comment: @b85411 You're welcome, I am glad my answer helped you